# How to use methods defined for parameters of type long with values of type Double?

Tags: java

I have this code where i try to define operations for numbers of type "Double", but I can see, that `addExact`, `subtractExact` and `multiplyExact` can only be used with long.

How can I use them for parameters of type Double?

```
// variable is static defining it here
static {
   operations = new HashMap<>();
   defineOperations();
}

// links to methods with operations...
private static void defineOperations() {
   operations.put("+",Math::addExact);
   operations.put("-", Math::subtractExact);
   operations.put("*", Math::multiplyExact);
   operations.put("/", DoubleStack::divide);
}
```

Comment: @SMA `java.lang.Math`?

Comment: Assuming this is `java.lang.Math`, you can only apply `addExact` to int and long operands because it's only defined for int and long operands. There is no double overload, because that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Just write your own `static` methods that perform the arithmetic operations on `double`s and use them instead; you can't make pre-written libraries do what they weren't written to do.

Comment: Even if you manage to use methods defined for long, you'd loose the decimal places of your Doubles. Probably you don't want that.